# Elegant and efficient way to find the median value based on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below but my real dataframe has millions of rows

```
te_df = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
                      'test':['test1','test2','test3','test1','test2','test3','test1','test4'],
              '0-24hrs':[1,1,1,2,1,1,np.nan,np.nan],
              '24-48hrs':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,1,2,1],
              '48-72hrs':[2,3,1,3,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
                    })
```

I would like to find the `median` number of times a test is conducted (identify `using test column`) every 24hours (using `0-24hrs`, `24-48hrs`, `48-72hrs`)

I tried the below

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame()
df_out['1st_24'] = te_df.groupby('test')['0-24hrs'].median()
df_out['2nd_24'] = te_df.groupby('test')['24-48hrs'].median()
df_out['3rd_24'] = te_df.groupby('test')['48-72hrs'].median()
```

Instead of repeating the same line thrice, is there any other efficient and elegant way to find this? Because my real dataframe has million of rows

Comment: What's wrong with `te_df.groupby('test').median()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this by:-

```
df_out=te_df.groupby('test').median().drop(columns=['subject_id'])

#output

       0-24hrs  24-48hrs    48-72hrs
test            
test1   1.5     1.5         2.5
test2   1.0     1.0         3.0
test3   1.0     1.0         1.0
test4   NaN     1.0         NaN
```

Note: In @BENY 's method access column values by passing a list you will not get a warning:

```
out = df.groupby('test')[['0-24hrs', '24-48hrs', '48-72hrs']].median()
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not try

```
out = df.groupby('test')[['0-24hrs', '24-48hrs', '48-72hrs']].median()
       0-24hrs  24-48hrs  48-72hrs
test                              
test1      1.5       1.5       2.5
test2      1.0       1.0       3.0
test3      1.0       1.0       1.0
test4      NaN       1.0       NaN
```

Comment: `FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.` :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang ah got you ~